# How to export a 3D model of just a particular frame?

Tags: animation, export, cloth-simulation

I created an animated cloth stimulation, so I need the object from a particular frame to be exported as a 3D model.

Comment: Hi. In which format do you want to export it? Gltf has this option for instance but not all the exporters.

Comment: I need it to be in .dae formate. The problem was solved thanks to Joonas. Thanks to u too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the frame you want and apply your modifiers. Including your cloth modifier. If you have Interface: Modifier Tools Add-on enabled you can press Apply All. If not then you can press the little down arrow and Apply. Or select a modifier and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. Remember to start from the top.

[image: Add modifiers]

Now your cloth is frozen and can be used as any 3D-object and exported from File and Export.

[image: Export]

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer helped you can click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.